# Datagirdview Filter

Tags: vb.net, search, datagridview

How do I filter `datagridview` using a textbox search ? I'm using vb.net 2012 and connect to access database using designer And buld datagridview wiht designer 
*my coulm i want search in named "color"

```
Public Class Form1 

    Private Sub SalesBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SalesBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.SalesBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.ds)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.SalesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ds.sales)
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub SalesDataGridView_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles SalesDataGridView.CellContentClick

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

The designer should have also created a BindingSource for you. In the textbox event you can apply the Filter to the BindingSource.Filter property.

`bindingSource.Filter = "[Color] = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"`

Comment: Thanks for replay .. when I type search words the dgviell show nothing and when I delete the search words the dgview show nothing ..... salesbindingSource.Filter = "[Color] = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"

Comment: Does the grid show any rows when you open the form.  Are you sure the datatable has data? You can also check the datagridview in the form designer to make sure the Datasource property is set to salesbindingSource.